# unable to install foundation with CLI

Tags: zurb-foundation, command-line-interface, zurb-foundation-6

I am new to zurb.
i am trying to install foundation using `CLI`

I used `npm install --global foundation-cli`

it installed foundation cli.
then i used

```
foundation new
```

But it says no arguments are called.
I think it should siplay a menu as written in a book
[image]

But mine is like this

[image]

Please tell me where am i doing it wrong. thanks

Comment: When you run `npm install --global foundation-cli` do you get the progress-bar or does it just skip straight to what's show above? There are references to this error on Github (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/issues/24 & https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-6/issues/241) but that seems to be to do with a conflicting version of Foundation, and it seems unlikely if you're using it for the first time. Do you have any other gems called "foundation"?

Answer (score -1):

You should simply type the name of your project after 'new'.

Comment: i did that but it installs a bower version. it dosen't come up with a menu